# SQLSVR not preparing statement correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, sqlsrv

Why is the paramter array not being prepared??? So weird, is it a bug in Sqlsrv Extenstion??

```
public $availableQueries = array("getOnlyCusips"=>"SELECT * FROM [THEDB] where [val] like '%?%' ",
                                "searchCusips"=>"SELECT * FROM [THEDB] where [val] = '?'");
function runQuery($query,$params){
    $connection = new connect;
    $conn = $connection->EstablishConnection();
    $sql = $this->availableQueries[$query];
    $params = explode(',',$params);
    */*************************BUG IN EXTENSION???, STR_REPLACE BAD FIX BELOW **************/*
    if($query=="getOnlyCusips"){
        $sql = str_replace("?",$params[0],$sql);
    }
    if($query=="searchCusips"){
        $sql = str_replace("?",$params[0],$sql);
    }
    */*************************BUG IN EXTENSION???, STR_REPLACE BAD FIX ABOVE**************/*
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, ($params));
    $returnObject=array();
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt,  SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        array_push($returnObject,$row);
    }
    $connection->closeConnection();
    return $returnObject;                           
}
```

Basically i am trying to place $params into the sqlsrv_query function to prepare the statements but its simply not. I have to do string_replace to replace the '?' with the param of interest. 
I am for sure using a properly formatted params array =Array("val1")

any ideas anyone? This STR_REPLACE wont work in the future when i need to insert more than 1 paramter

Comment: Guessing mode (because I don't know what `class connect` does under the hood): `'` marks a string literal. A parameter is not a string literal. `where [val] = ?` and `where [val] like ? ` (and then you have to add the %% to the actual parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace `?` with the values in `$params`.

`sqlsrv_query` automatically replaces them under the hood as **parameters** in order to avoid sql injection.

If you replace with `str_replace`, your code is vulnerable.

Also, `$params` must be an array of arrays, not just a single array. At the end, `$params` should be like:

```
$params = array( array( "val1" ) );
```

After executing your query with `sqlsrv_query`, always check if there is any error with `sqlsrv_errors()` function.

Comment: that my issue, i am doing it this way and am usring sqlsrv_query but its not preparing the statement correclty so i did the str_replace as a temporary fix. Can it be that the latest sqlsrv extension is buggy?

Comment: @BenChen I don't think so. What exactly is `$paarms`? Do you try to remove `'` from your queries? Do you have any error on PHP or SQLSRV?

Comment: no error but  $params = array("value"); but I did try $params = array(array("value")); and they both don't prepare the statement

Comment: @BenChen what do you mean with 'they don't prepare the statement'? What is the return value of `runQuery()`? There must be some output from `sqlsrv_query()`, because it prepares and executes the statement, so check errors with `sqlsrv_errors()`.